# Can I access VM's IP inside pod?

Tags: kubernetes, ip, kubernetes-pod

I have installed kubernetes on my VM. And I run my application inside pod on kubernetes.

Now I want to get IP address of my VM in my application which is running inside pod.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get the host IP:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["ash","-c","echo $MY_HOST_IP && sleep 3600"]
    env:
    - name: MY_HOST_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

`kubectl logs busybox` will print you the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to  get the host ip and the hostname from the pod running on a specific node. Use the below variable to get those values

```
spec.nodeName - the name of the node to which the scheduler always attempts to schedule the pod
status.hostIP - the IP of the node to which the Pod is assigned
```

following link would be helpful --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/